# SQL Server : find last time user was connected

Tags: sql-server

I have a SQL Server (2000) with a number of accounts which I think are no longer used.
Is there any way I can find out when each account was last used?

Alternatively what is the easiest way to create a table of accounts logging on to the server over a period.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

SQL Server can audit logins. Read more detail [here for SQL 2008](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175850.aspx) and [here for SQL 2000](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd277388.aspx)

I do not think you can track login usage unless the auditing is turned on.

Comment: If you switch on C2 auditing, you fill your hard disk quickly on a busy server with trace files. And where did you get info on accdate from in syslogins?

Comment: Good info, I created a job that runs every minute that merges this info into a table so I can look at that table anytime and see the last login. Works great for my purpose.

Comment: I just tested whether accdate is updated with the latest login time and it is not.

Answer (score 0):

If the user is listed under the folder "Security"-->"Logins", this query will give you the last date/time that user signed in.

```
select name, accdate from sys.syslogins order by 1
```

NOTE: This only works for those IDs that currently exist in the SQL database.  If the ID was deleted, it will not appear on the list.

I'm not sure if this will work for SQL 2000, but I also use this for later versions of SQL to get the last login name and date:

```
SELECT DISTINCT 
Rtrim(sp.loginame) as loginname,
sp.login_time
FROM   master..sysprocesses sp
WHERE  sp.login_time IN (SELECT Max(login_time)
                         FROM   master..sysprocesses
                         GROUP  BY loginame)
       AND sp.loginame NOT LIKE ( '##%' )
```

And I use this to get some more information about the last login date for a user:

```
SELECT Max(sp.login_time) AS LastLoginTime, 
       Max(sp.last_batch) AS LastBatchTime, 
       sp.hostname, 
       sp.program_name, 
       sp.loginame, 
       sd.NAME            AS DatabaseName 
FROM   sys.sysprocesses sp 
       JOIN sys.databases sd 
         ON sp.dbid = sd.database_id 
WHERE  ( sp.loginame NOT LIKE 'NT SERVICE%' 
         AND sp.loginame NOT LIKE 'NT AUTHORITY%' ) 
GROUP  BY sp.hostname, 
          sp.program_name, 
          sp.loginame, 
          sd.NAME 
ORDER  BY Max(sp.login_time)
```

Comment: Not working for me here on SQL Server 2012. "accdate" is not updated.

Comment: Accdate doesn't seem to exist in SQL Azure

Comment: Works on 2008 :)

Comment: Damn - this looks so right, but accdate = createdate on every row! (And MS article for 2008 onward says this functionality is not guaranteed in future) - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-compatibility-views/sys-syslogins-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017

Comment: query worked on SQL 2000 with syslogins rather than sys.syslogins, but looks like accdate is when account created (same as createdate).   Updatedate when password last changed? So no record here of last log in for SQL 2000.