# Detect last login date/time in SQL Server 2000

Tags: sql, sql-server, audit

Is there a way of determining when a given user last logged into SQL Server?  We are about to carry out an audit of our database server and would like to delete users that are redundant.

Incidentally I'm interested in users at the server-level (i.e. Logins), not users of individual databases.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [SQL Server : find last time user was connected](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1278609/sql-server-find-last-time-user-was-connected)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Even if you have Login auditing for successful logins enabled, it depends how far back your SQL errorlogs go.

[SQL Server 2000 Auditing](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd277388.aspx)

Comment: Is there any way I can hook into the login process going forward?  I am only interested in capturing active users going forward.  Also, Is it possible to enable login auditing on SQL Server 2000, or is this only a later feature?

Comment: It's a SQL Server 2000 feature

Answer (score 2):

I asked this question before...

[sql-server-find-last-time-user-was-connected](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1278609/sql-server-find-last-time-user-was-connected)

I think I ended up running some sql that read master..sysprocesses for new logins at regular intervals over a period using sql agent.

Answer (score 0):

Check out [Logon Triggers](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb326598.aspx) (available since SQL Server 2005)