# SQL Logins which are not logged into Server more than 6 months

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, logging, authentication

I have a query regarding the SQL Login-

We need to filter the database logins which are not logged into database more that 6 months.
i am not able to find out relevant SQL for the same.

Kindly advice asap.

Comment: possible duplicate of [SQL Server : find last time user was connected](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1278609/sql-server-find-last-time-user-was-connected)

Comment: [See this Serverfault question](http://serverfault.com/questions/74991/find-last-login-datetime-for-sql-server-login) - seems that information is **not** available by default. You would have to set up some login triggers and auditing tables yourself, in order to track this