# SQL Server 2016 - How to get last logged in date for user?

Tags: sql-server, database-administration

How can I get the last logged in date for certain user.
I googled and stumbled upon this query

```
SELECT name, accdate FROM sys.syslogins
```

But the `accdate` column seems to be deprecated, and does not update.

I have another clue

```
SELECT login_name, max(login_time) as last_logged_in 
FROM sys.dm_exec_sessions GROUP BY login_name
```

But it shows me results only for system users, not the ones which I created with this query

```
CREATE USER test1 FOR LOGIN test1 WITH DEFAULT_SCHEMA = 'test1'
```

The question is, how to make custom created users appear in `sys.dm_exec_sessions`, or what's the alternative to that solution?

Comment: Not sure why, but `accdate` is actually the same as `createdate`. If you look at the DDL of `sys.syslogins` you'll see that they are defined as ` createdate = p.create_date` and `accdate = p.create_date`. I'm not sure that you can get the Login Dates from SQL Server. You'll likely need to set up some kind of extended event to store this information. I *suppose* you could also set up a Server Level Trigger as well, but just make sure the table your inserting to is accessible by public, and no users have `DENY` (otherwise they won't be able to log in). I don't really recommend a `TRIGGER`.

Comment: You might have more joy with this question over on [Stack DBA](https://dba.stackexchange.com/).  As @Larnu said I don't think SQL Server does this, out of the box.  Investigate [extended events](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb630354%28v=sql.105%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396).

Comment: Near-duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1278609/sql-server-find-last-time-user-was-connected

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Use [sys.dm_exec_sessions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-dynamic-management-views/sys-dm-exec-sessions-transact-sql) system view That

> shows information about all active user connections and internal
>   tasks. This information includes client version, client program name,
>   **client login time**, login user, current session setting, and more.

Here’s a little script hopes help you out!

```
SELECT login_name [Login] , MAX(login_time) AS [Last Login Time]
FROM sys.dm_exec_sessions
GROUP BY login_name;
```

**UPDATE**

And About New logins, You Must Login with them firstly for getting a record into `sys.dm_exec_sessions`

so use the next code for creating a login:-

```
CREATE LOGIN NewAdminName WITH PASSWORD = 'ABCDa@12'
GO
CREATE USER [NewAdminName] FOR LOGIN [NewAdminName]
EXEC sp_addrolemember N'db_owner', N'NewAdminName'
```

Now Login by:-

```
User Name = NewAdminName

Password: ABCDa@12
```

After Logging successfully, the information of this login is stored into `sys.dm_exec_sessions`

Comment: I already did that. The problem is there are no users which I needed. For example, I have user ```test1``` but there's no data in that view for this user. Would be great, if I could "push" that user there somehow, and to turn logging for that user as well

Comment: You MUST login firstly by user name that you created for getting a record into `sys.dm_exec_sessions `

Comment: Thanks! I'm afraid I can't login by other users

Comment: so there is no record inserted unless logging succeeded !

Comment: I am using SQL Server 2017.  When I close my desktop app record immediately disappears and when I close a connection in SSMS it stays. Only certain thing is that there is no active login that is not shown in sys.dm_exec_sessions, I hope. Not useful for trying to find out when was login last logged in.

Comment: In SSMS when I browse: Server\Instance > Security > Logins, I see logins listed which do not appear in the results of the script given in this answer. Does this mean those logins have never logged in? Or could it mean they are not currently logged in? I am wanting to know the last time a login credential has been used.

Comment: Yeah, the docs for sys.dm_exec_sessions say "Returns one row per authenticated session on SQL Server" - so this answer does not tell you when system logins last logged in that are no longer part of active sessions.

Comment: Downvoted as this is not doing what the question asks for. 

"active user connections" is not at all the same thing as "last login date per server login/principal".

Answer (score 4):

```
select DISTINCT login_time, host_name, program_name, login_name from
(SELECT sys.dm_exec_sessions.*,
RANK() OVER(PARTITION BY login_name ORDER BY login_time DESC) as rnk
FROM sys.dm_exec_sessions) l
where l.rnk = 1
ORDER BY l.login_time DESC
```

Answer (score 2):

By default the last login date isn't recorded by SQL Server :'(

There's a variety of ways you can record it yourself, e.g.

- Extended Events session to record logins (e.g. see [this article](https://www.sqlshack.com/creating-a-sql-server-audit-using-sql-server-extended-events-and-triggers/)), then you query that to get what you want. There's a "Connection Tracking" template that probably records the info you need.
- Triggers (ugh, not recommended)
- [SQL Server Audit](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/security/auditing/sql-server-audit-database-engine?view=sql-server-ver15) feature (which like Extended Events is super flexible but hard to get your head around when all you want is the last login date).
- A SQL Agent Job that periodically looks at the current logins by querying [sys.dm_exec_sessions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-dynamic-management-views/sys-dm-exec-sessions-transact-sql) system view. I wouldn't recommend this since it's highly possible you'll miss some logins, plus it puts a higher load than using the extended events infrastructure that SQL provides.