# How to get the user last login date and time in SQL Server?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2005

How to get the user last login date and time in SQL Server?

I want to get the user last login date & time. Is there any inbuilt SP available in SQL server ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [SQL Server : find last time user was connected](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1278609/sql-server-find-last-time-user-was-connected)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT login_name AS UserLogin , max(login_time) lastlogin
FROM sys.dm_exec_sessions
GROUP BY login_name;
```

Comment: But i am getting only last login session values. Not contains user login history. I am going to use for the auditing purpose so i need all users last login details.